# Accessing SAP tables via JCo

Tags: java, sap-erp, jco

I'm currently using SAP JCo to connect to SAP system and fetch the data from the SAP tables. I'm using the internal BAPI functions to fetch the data from SAP tables. I would like to know the approach of how to fetch the data from SAP tables, by just specifying the table name and the columns from which the data should be retrieved.

Below is the code that I'm using to fetch data via the BAPI functions.

Any help on how to access the SAP tables by specifying just the table name and columns is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

```
JCoFunction function = destination.getRepository().getFunction("BAPI_COMPANYCODE_GETLIST");
    if(function == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("BAPI_COMPANYCODE_GETLIST not found in SAP.");

    try
    {
        function.execute(destination);
    }
    catch(AbapException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        return;
    }
    
    JCoStructure returnStructure = function.getExportParameterList().getStructure("RETURN");
    if (! (returnStructure.getString("TYPE").equals("")||returnStructure.getString("TYPE").equals("S"))  )   
    {
       throw new RuntimeException(returnStructure.getString("MESSAGE"));
    }
    
    JCoTable codes = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("COMPANYCODE_LIST");
    final FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("D:\\out.csv");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < codes.getNumRows(); i++) 
    {
        codes.setRow(i);
      
    }
    
    
    codes.firstRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < codes.getNumRows(); i++, codes.nextRow()) 
    {
        function = destination.getRepository().getFunction("BAPI_COMPANYCODE_GETDETAIL");
        if (function == null) 
            throw new RuntimeException("BAPI_COMPANYCODE_GETDETAIL not found in SAP.");
        
        function.getImportParameterList().setValue("COMPANYCODEID", codes.getString("COMP_CODE"));
        function.getExportParameterList().setActive("COMPANYCODE_ADDRESS",false);
        
        try
        {
            function.execute(destination);
        }
        catch (AbapException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return;
        }

        returnStructure = function.getExportParameterList().getStructure("RETURN");
        if (! (returnStructure.getString("TYPE").equals("") ||
               returnStructure.getString("TYPE").equals("S") ||
               returnStructure.getString("TYPE").equals("W")) ) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(returnStructure.getString("MESSAGE"));
        }
        
        JCoStructure detail = function.getExportParameterList().getStructure("COMPANYCODE_DETAIL");
```

Answer (score 0):

To access SAP Tables just by specifying just the table name and columns, use the RFC [RFC_READ_TABLE](https://www.sapdatasheet.org/abap/func/rfc_read_table.html) (External access to R/3 tables via RFC)

- parameter **QUERY_TABLE** - specify the table name here
- (optional) parameter **ROWSKIPS** - skip the first records
- (optional) parameter **ROWCOUNT** - max row count to be loaded, for performance considerations